# handleCallback,MyViewHolder.onClick

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

Am getting an unexpected error in Android studio while running the app and click on the target image the app is crash and the following error message which am getting.

````
    Process: com.salman.firebasecomicreaderapp, PID: 2874
    android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?
        at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:952)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:928)
        at com.salman.firebasecomicreaderapp.Adapter.MyComicAdapter$1.onClick(MyComicAdapter.java:53)
        at com.salman.firebasecomicreaderapp.Adapter.MyComicAdapter$MyViewHolder.onClick(MyComicAdapter.java:89)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7125)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7102)
        at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:801)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27336)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)```
````

Comment: Provide some more details where  you are getting this error. Seems you are starting an activity without having application context.

Comment: //Event
        myViewHolder.setRecyclerItemClickListener(new IRecyclerItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view, int position) {
                //Save Comic Selected
                Common.comicSelected = comicList.get(position);
                context.startActivity(new Intent(context,ChapteraActivity.class));

            }
        });

Comment: @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            recyclerItemClickListener.onClick(view,getAdapterPosition());
        }
    }

Comment: when i click on these errors they take me to above comments methods

Comment: Are you setting context from your activity ?

Answer (score 2):

Either you are not correctly caching the context object or you are running in **Android 28(Android P)**

try the following way

```java
myViewHolder.setRecyclerItemClickListener(new IRecyclerItemClickListener() { @Override public void onClick(View view, int position) { 
   Intent intent = new Intent(context,ChapteraActivity.class);
   if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
      intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
   }
  context.startActivity(intent);
 } 
});
```

Comment: Hey [Chek-This](https://github.com/afsaredrisy/RecyclerViewDemo). Are you trying to to do something like this as I did in this small application?  or something else. OR you share some of your code of Adapter , ViewHolder and Activity otherwise it is difficult to guess what is going wrong.